# Showing a set is closed under inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group, say a group with $n$ elements, and let $\emptyset \neq S \subseteq G$. Suppose $e \in S$, and that $S$ is closed with respect to multiplication. Prove
that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

Let $G = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}.$ Let $a_i \in G.$ Then any number of $a_ia_1, a_ia_2, \ldots, a_ia_n \in S,$ since $S$ is closed under multiplication. One of those $a_ia_j$ is $e$ since $e \in S.$ Then either $a_i$ or $a_j$ is $a^{-1}.$ Would this argument work?

Comment: what is $a$????

Comment: Meant to say $(a_i)^{-1}$ or $(a_j)^{-1}.$

Comment: where did you used that $G$ is finite?

Comment: $G = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$

Comment: what would go wrong if you write $G=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots\}$??

Comment: This doesn't prove anything, you just showed that an element in $G$ has an inverse

Comment: @ Praphulla Koushik, that's not given.

Comment: what is not given?? I am asking a simple question... why do you want $G$ to be finite??

Comment: Because in the problem it's stated that $G$ must be finite.

Comment: you are not getting my point... Fine... Do you think what you have done is correct?? Ask yourself... Have you really used all conditions that are given?? take some time..

Comment: I think the finiteness condition has been used implicitly here. You need to justify that the $a_ia_j$ are distinct for this argument to work fully.

Comment: @ Mathmo123, in my book it says "If $a_i \in G$, consider the *distinct* elements $a_ia_1, a_ia_2, \ldots, a_ia_n.$" Does that mean the "distinctness condition" is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need $G$ to be finite...

It is enough if you assume $S$ is finite...

let $S=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_n\}$ and set $e=a_1$ identity element...

Take $a_2\in S$ and consider $M=\{a_2a_j : 1\leq j\leq n\}$..

Check 1 : Prove that $a_2a_j\neq a_2a_i$ for any $i\neq j$..

Chek 2 : So cardinality of $M$ is ???

Check 3 : As $S$ is closed under multiplication $M\subseteq S$

Check 4 : Using cardinality of $M$ see that $M=S$ (this is where you use finiteness of $S$)

Check 5 : As $e\in S$ we should have $e\in M=\{a_2a_j : 1\leq j\leq n\}$.. So, $e=a_2a_j$ for some $j$...

I have already said more than enough....  :D

Note : For $S$ to be invertible you want inverse of $a_2$ to be in $S$..

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the fact that a finite monoid with cancellation must be a group. It's the group analogue of the fact that a finite domain is a field.

In both cases, the proof comes from considering the map $x \mapsto ax$. Cancellation implies that this map is injective. Finiteness then implies that the map is surjective. So $1$ is in the image of the map and this gives an inverse for $a$.

Cancellation holds because your monoid is inside a group.